# Smooth (Inertial) Scrolling with SDL2?

Tags: c++, scroll, sdl, sdl-2

I am building **SDL2** applications for **macOS** using C++. I need some "basic" scrolling for an app (like a web browser). I achieve that using the **SDL_MouseWheel event**, which gives me a fully functional "windows-like" scrolling. I am using a Macbook Pro and I want to bring the trackpad's functionality in.

Simply, I am asking for a better scrolling algorithm (**Macbook's trackpad scrolling, inertial scrolling**)

I know about the **SDL_MultiGesture event**, but I don't really know how to put things together to achieve the result I want.

Comment: Question seems a bit vague and broad in scope.  Can you narrow it down a bit, perhaps giving an example of what you currently have and explain how you want to alter the behaviour?

Comment: I want to implement inertial scrolling using SDL2 (probably with SDL_MultiGesture) and I want some help or example for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, here's the answer to the problem.

First of all, you will have to do it manually.
I also assume that you know SDL2 and C++.
***Note:** I'm doing scrolling only for Y-Axis (you can do it for both if you want).

Firstly we will need some variables:

```
int    scrolling;               // flag (scrolling or not)
int    scroll_sensitivity = 40; // how fast we want to scroll
double scroll_Y = 0;            // current scrolling amount (on Y-Axis)
double scroll_acceleration;     // scrolling speed
double scroll_friction = 0.001; // how fast we decelerate
double scroll_prev_pos;         // previous event's position
```

After that you will need to handle the SDL_MultiGesture event:

```
case SDL_MULTIGESTURE:{
  if(event.mgesture.numFingers == 2){
    if(scrolling == 0){
      scrolling = 1;
      scroll_prev_pos = event.mgesture.y;
    } else{
      double dy = event.mgesture.y - scroll_prev_pos;
      scroll_acceleration = dy * 40;
      scroll_prev_pos = event.mgesture.y;
      scrolling = 1;
    }
  }
  break;
}
```

Also, we need to stop scrolling on SDL_FingerDown event:

```
case SDL_FINGERDOWN:{
  scrolling = 0;
  break;
}
```

Next, we want to update scroll_Y (put it in your "update" function):

```
if(scrolling){
  if(scroll_acceleration > 0) scroll_acceleration -= scroll_friction;
  if(scroll_acceleration < 0) scroll_acceleration += scroll_friction;
  if(abs(scroll_acceleration) < 0.0005) scroll_acceleration = 0;
  scroll_Y += scroll_sensitivity * scroll_acceleration;
  // Here you have to set your scrolling bounds i.e. if(scroll_Y < 0) scroll_Y = 0;
}
```

Finally, we want to render according to our scroll values:

```
SDL_Rect rect = {some_x, some_y + scroll_Y, some_w, some_h};
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, some_texture, NULL, &rect);
```

**This is it!**
I have a fully working app with the above code, so I'm 100% sure that this works as supposed. If you have any problems (because it's not actual code, it's more like an algorithm) contact me. As I mentioned before, I assume that you already know good enough SDL and C++, so I believe that you are able to understand the implementation.
Also, I know that this solution can become better, so if you have anything to add / change, just say it!

**Have a nice day!**

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue, and it turns out that SDL [opts out of momentum scroll events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DriversKernelHardware/RN-MagicMouse/) by turning off the `AppleMomentumScrollSupported` default in the user defaults system.

You can turn this back on in your application with the following bit of Objective-C++, and your `SDL_MouseWheel` events will become smoothed.

```m
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"AppleMomentumScrollSupported",
                            nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[appDefaults release];
```

Comment: This way doesn't seem to work anymore. See Martijn's answer below for the same thing in a style that works

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, @Aleski's answer doesn't work anymore. The new way to hack this feature back on is:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: YES
                                       forKey: @"AppleMomentumScrollSupported"];
```